# Revit Addin Runs When Form is Closed

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, revit-api

My program in Revit has two list boxes and depending on what is selected, it will make changes to elements. However, I have found that if a user selects some options but then closes the form, it will still run with the selected options. My code is below. I tried to add a Form_Closing method based on what I have found online but my Execute method runs all the way through none-the-less.

I have an if statement in the execute method that should return Result.Cancelled and should stop the program. I feel that it has something to do with the event of my Form_Closing method. Thank you for the help.

```
    namespace CircuitCheck
{
    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
    [RegenerationAttribute(RegenerationOption.Manual)]
    public class Command : IExternalCommand
    {
        private static Autodesk.Revit.DB.Color color;
        private static OverrideGraphicSettings ogs;
        private static OverrideGraphicSettings ogsOriginal;
        private static Boolean cancelled;


        public Command()
        {
            color = new Autodesk.Revit.DB.Color(138, 43, 226); // RGB
            ogs = new OverrideGraphicSettings();
            ogsOriginal = new OverrideGraphicSettings();
            ogs.SetProjectionLineColor(color);
            cancelled = false;
        }


        public partial class CircuitCheckerForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
        {
            private Boolean CheckClicked;
            public CircuitCheckerForm(IWin32Window owner)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.ShowDialog(owner);
            }

            public String[] getSelectionElementsLB()
            {
                String[] sel = new String[7];
                int count = 0;
                foreach ( object li in ElementsLB.SelectedItems )
                {
                    String text = li.ToString();
                    sel[count] = text;
                    count++;
                }
                return sel;
            }
            public String getSelectionPlaceLB()
            {
                return PaceLB.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }

            private void Check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Hide();
                CheckClicked = true;
            }

            private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

            private void Form_Closing(FormClosedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (!CheckClicked)
                {
                    cancelled = true;
                    this.Close();
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
                }
            }

            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing && (components != null))
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                CheckClicked = false;

               //setup for form not shown

            }
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox PaceLB;
            private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox ElementsLB;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Button Check;
        }
        class RevisionData
        {
            //public int Sequence { get; set; }
            //public RevisionNumberType Numbering { get; set; }
            //public string Date { get; set; }
            //public string Description { get; set; }
            //public bool Issued { get; set; }
            //public string IssuedTo { get; set; }
            //public string IssuedBy { get; set; }
            //public RevisionVisibility Show { get; set; }
        }




        public Result Execute(
      ExternalCommandData commandData,
      ref string message,
      ElementSet elements)
        {
            Document document = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
            using (Transaction trans = new Transaction(document))
            {
                IWin32Window revit_window
              = new JtWindowHandle(
                ComponentManager.ApplicationWindow);

                UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
                UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
                Document doc = uidoc.Document;
                trans.Start("Check");
                if (doc.IsFamilyDocument)
                {
                    TaskDialog.Show("Not a Revit RVT Project",
                      "This command requires an active Revit RVT file.");

                    return Result.Failed;
                }





                Boolean messedUp = true;
                Boolean All = false, lightF = false, recep = false, elecEquip = false, equipCon = false, justView = true;

                while (messedUp)
                {
                    CircuitCheckerForm form = new CircuitCheckerForm(revit_window);
                    if(cancelled) //**************************************
                    {
                        trans.Dispose();
                        return Result.Cancelled;
                    }             //**************************************
                    String[] item = form.getSelectionElementsLB();
                    int numSel = 0;
                    for (int x = 0; x < item.Length; x++)
                    {
                        if (item[x] != null)
                        {
                            if (item[x].Equals("All"))
                            {
                                All = true;
                                messedUp = false;
                                numSel++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (item[x].Equals("Ligthing Fixtures"))
                            {
                                lightF = true;
                                messedUp = false;
                                numSel++;
                            }
                            else if (item[x].Equals("Recepticales"))
                            {
                                recep = true;
                                messedUp = false;
                                numSel++;
                            }
                            else if (item[x].Equals("Electrical Equipment (including Panels)"))
                            {
                                elecEquip = true;
                                messedUp = false;
                                numSel++;
                            }
                            else if (item[x].Equals("Equipment Connection"))
                            {
                                equipCon = true;
                                messedUp = false;
                                numSel++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(numSel == 0)
                    {
                        TaskDialog.Show("Error", "No elements were selected for checking. Please relaunch the program to try again.");
                        trans.Dispose();
                        return Result.Failed;
                    }

                    if (form.getSelectionPlaceLB().Equals("Entire Project"))
                    {
                        justView = false;
                    }
                    else if (form.getSelectionPlaceLB().Equals("Elements in Current View"))
                    {
                        justView = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        messedUp = true;
                        TaskDialog.Show("Error", "A place must be selected.");
                    }


                    int notCircuited = 0;


                    Autodesk.Revit.DB.View view = doc.ActiveView;




                    if (All)
                    {
                        if (justView)
                        {
                            notCircuited += CheckLightF(doc, doc.ActiveView);
                            notCircuited += CheckRecep(doc, doc.ActiveView);
                            notCircuited += CheckElecEquip(doc, doc.ActiveView);
                            notCircuited += CheckEquipCon(doc, doc.ActiveView);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            FilteredElementCollector viewCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(document);
                            viewCollector.OfClass(typeof(Autodesk.Revit.DB.ViewPlan));

                            foreach (Element viewElement in viewCollector)
                            {
                                Autodesk.Revit.DB.View view2 = (Autodesk.Revit.DB.View)viewElement;
                                notCircuited += CheckLightF(doc, view2);
                                notCircuited += CheckRecep(doc, view2);
                                notCircuited += CheckElecEquip(doc, view2);
                                notCircuited += CheckEquipCon(doc, view2);
                            }

                        }
                        if (notCircuited == 0)
                        {
                            TaskDialog.Show("Circuit Checker", notCircuited + " elements are not circuited in this view.\nYou did good, mate.");
                            trans.Commit();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            TaskDialog.Show("Circuit Checker", notCircuited + " elements are not circuited in this view.\nGet your shit together...");
                            trans.Commit();
                        }
                    }

                    if (!trans.HasEnded())
                    {
                        if (lightF)
                        {
                            if (justView)
                            {
                                notCircuited += CheckLightF(doc, doc.ActiveView);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                FilteredElementCollector viewCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(document);
                                viewCollector.OfClass(typeof(Autodesk.Revit.DB.ViewPlan));

                                foreach (Element viewElement in viewCollector)
                                {
                                    Autodesk.Revit.DB.View view2 = (Autodesk.Revit.DB.View)viewElement;
                                    notCircuited += CheckLightF(doc, view2);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (recep)
                        {
                            if (justView)
                            {
                                notCircuited += CheckRecep(doc, doc.ActiveView);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                FilteredElementCollector viewCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(document);
                                viewCollector.OfClass(typeof(Autodesk.Revit.DB.ViewPlan));

                                foreach (Element viewElement in viewCollector)
                                {
                                    Autodesk.Revit.DB.View view2 = (Autodesk.Revit.DB.ViewPlan)viewElement;
                                    notCircuited += CheckRecep(doc, view2);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (elecEquip)
                        {
                            if (justView)
                            {
                                notCircuited += CheckElecEquip(doc, doc.ActiveView);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                FilteredElementCollector viewCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(document);
                                viewCollector.OfClass(typeof(Autodesk.Revit.DB.ViewPlan));

                                foreach (Element viewElement in viewCollector)
                                {
                                    Autodesk.Revit.DB.View view2 = (Autodesk.Revit.DB.ViewPlan)viewElement;
                                    notCircuited += CheckElecEquip(doc, view2);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (equipCon)
                        {
                            if (justView)
                            {
                                notCircuited += CheckEquipCon(doc, doc.ActiveView);
                            }
                            else
                            {


                                FilteredElementCollector viewCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(document);
                                viewCollector.OfClass(typeof(Autodesk.Revit.DB.ViewPlan));

                                foreach (Element viewElement in viewCollector)
                                {
                                    Autodesk.Revit.DB.View view2 = (Autodesk.Revit.DB.ViewPlan)viewElement;
                                    notCircuited += CheckEquipCon(doc, view2);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (notCircuited == 0)
                        {
                            TaskDialog.Show("Circuit Checker", notCircuited + " elements are not circuited in this view.\nYou did good, mate.");
                            trans.Commit();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            TaskDialog.Show("Circuit Checker", notCircuited + " elements are not circuited in this view.\nGet your shit together...");
                            trans.Commit();
                        }
                    }

                }


                return Result.Succeeded;
            }
        }

        //some methods used are not shown as they are only used in the execute method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Execute` method will be called on another thread than the GUI thread - the `while` loop won't see the update... you'll need to figure out a way for the two threads to signal each other.

Or even better: Set up an ExternalEvent handler instead of the while loop and use the body of the while loop as the body of the event handler. Start the handler in the `Execute` method and stop it when the window get's closed.